# Theming a node/add form in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

I have a statement in my template.php file that directs to a custom node-myccktype.tpl.php. I've added some DIV's so that I can have a two column node/add form, but now I'm trying to find print my fields, but can't seem to get it.

I'm basically using something like this:

```
<?php print form_render($form['field_sr_minutes']); ?>
```

which I came across on a Drupal Blog, but I get call to undefined function "form_render"

I am using the var_dump to get the the array below, how can I print my node title(subject) field without printing everything else? This way I can put each form field in the column I want Instead of the standard vertical drupal form.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [#type] => textfield
            [#title] => Subject
            [#required] => 1
            [#default_value] => 
            [#maxlength] => 255
            [#weight] => -5
            [#post] => Array
                (
                )

            [#programmed] => 
            [#tree] => 
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => title
                )

            [#array_parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => title
                )

            [#processed] => 1
            [#description] => 
            [#attributes] => Array
                (
                )

            [#input] => 1
            [#size] => 60
            [#autocomplete_path] => 
            [#process] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_expand_ahah
                )

            [#name] => title
            [#id] => edit-title
            [#value] => 
            [#defaults_loaded] => 1
            [#sorted] => 1
        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry. Because of your .tpl file name I thought that you were trying to theme a node view. For forms, the right function is not `form_render` but `drupal_render`. You can basically write things like `echo drupal_render($form['field_sr_minutes'])` . In the very end, remember to do a `drupal_render($form)` to render all the remaining things which you have not rendered by hand. This will be required to have the form working correctly.

**Old Answer**

> The node.tpl.php and other content
>   type specific .tpl.php get passed the
>   full node object in `$node`. Try doing
>   a
>   `drupal_set_message(print_r($node,TRUE))`
>   on top of your tpl file. From that you
>   can figure out the exact path of the
>   values you need to print.
>
> For example, title of the node will be
>   available in $node->title. However you
>   should be careful to always use
>   `check_plain` if you are going to
>   print user submitted values. For CCK
>   fields, you can find the already
>   filtered values in `$node-><field
>   name>[0][view]`.

Comment: drupal_set_message(print_r($node,TRUE)) in the .tpl doesn't output anything. Nor does $node->field_sr_status[0]['view'] where field_sr_status is the name of my field.

Comment: Sorry. Misunderstood your question. Updated the answer. May be this would help.

Comment: I'll throw you a +1...you solved a problem that was driving me nuts as well ^_^